# Html Form with Google App Script - Communicating with code behind and showing output

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a small web app project that enables an Html form to communicate with App script. I initially attempted to use doGet() and doPost(): the doPost() is initiated automatically when the form in the HTML is submitted, however, the final line, supposedly redirecting to another HTML page: Thanks.html, is never hit. I asked another question and some people tried to set me into the right direction. I tried another solution, stripped off all functionality, and am simply trying to use:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandle).returnOK();
```

However, the returnOK() function in App script, is never hit. When I click the button, the HTML form disappears, and the log (first thing in the returnOK() script) is never logged, which means the script is never accessed. Snippets from my code with the most important bits below.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE):
}

function returnOK(){
    Logger.log("ok");
    return "ok";
}

function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).getContent();
}
```

index.html

```
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
<div id="mainDiv">
    <form id="form">
        <img src="..." /> 
        <table>...</table>
        <label>...</label> <br/>
        <div>...</div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
     </form>
 </div>
 <?!= include('Javascript'); ?>
```

Javascript.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function submit(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandle).returnOK();
}

function successHandle(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = 'Thank you';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Put console.log(e) in your successHandle() function and see what it logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a function with the form as argument.

An (even more simplified) example below (only the html part, the gs is unchanged) :

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <form id="form">
        <div id="output">response here</div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="update(this)">
     </form>
 </div>


<script>
function update(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandle).returnOK();
}

function successHandle(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = 'Thank you, answer = '+e;
}
</script>
```

Comment: this worked. thanks a lot! could you kindly explain to me, how your solution is any better than mine?

Comment: when you submit a form, the default behavior is to hide the form and -eventually- show the response in a brand new content. Using a random function allows to decide what we show or hide manually.  note also that the native mode is not necessary, remove it to use the default iFrame mode which is far more compatible with about everything.

Comment: and how do you use the input values as parameters in the update().. for e.g. function update(e) { } and then be able to use: e.parameter.paramName?

Comment: depending of the kind of object you return the method will be different... if you return a JS object that has properties the it will be e.propertyName, if you return an array it will be e[0], e[1]... you can do about everything you want.